# GameObject not visually displaying in the Scene Tab in the correct location in Unity Networking

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to add little things on top of the tutorials Unity supplies and I am confused about how to get this certain mechanic to work.

When my player shoots it shoots in the direction of the mouse.  When I run a client and host on my computer so that 2 people are connect for testing I get weird results.

I have both of my players shooting in the correct direction but when I am moving my mouse on one of the clients I see that my blue circle (which represents where the bullets will be spawned) is moving when that client is not focused, meaning I am not currently clicked on that client and when I am moving my mouse I see the blue circle moving on the client I am not focused on which I am not sure if my friend down the street was to test this would it cause errors.

Here are 2 screenshots of my Scene/Game view to get a better visual : [Pic 1](http://clip2net.com/s/3IkKIz9) - [Pic 2](http://clip2net.com/s/3IkKQIk)

I ended up using Network Transform Child on my parent GameObject for one of my children GameObjects that helps spawn the location of the bullets but still the visual look from my Scene tab makes me worry about the accuracy of bullets being spawned.

Here is my shooting code that :

```
public class PlayerShooting : NetworkBehaviour 
{
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public GameObject fireSpot;
public float bulletSpeed;
public Transform rotater;
public Camera cam;

void Update()
{
    // Only run the below code if this is the local player.
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Rotate based on the location of the mouse our spot to shoot bullets.
    Vector3 dir = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition) - rotater.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rotater.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward);

    // When we hit spacebar
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // Fire some bullets.
        CmdFire ();
    }
}


//  Something the client is wanting to be done and sends this "command" to the server to be processed
[Command]
public void CmdFire () 
{
    // Create the Bullet from the Bullet Prefab
    var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (bulletPrefab, fireSpot.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    // Add velocity to the bullet
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (fireSpot.transform.position - rotater.position).normalized * bulletSpeed;

    // Spawn the bullets for the Clients.
    NetworkServer.Spawn (bullet);

    // Destroy the bullet after 2 seconds
    Destroy(bullet, 4.0f);
}
}
```

My movement script :

```
public class Movement : NetworkBehaviour {

void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;
    var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

    transform.Translate(x, y, 0f);
}
}
```

Comment: Aww someone removed my previous comment.  Probably the same person who voted to close this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will continue to be a problem if you'd like to run multiple instances of unity games on the same machine.  If you go into *Edit > Project Settings > Player*, there is a *Run in Background* option under *Resolution and Presentation*.  If you have this checked, both instances of the game will receive updated mouse positions per frame from `Input.mousePosition` (Keep in mind `Input.GetKeyDown` will only register to the focused instance of the game so there's some inconsistency here).  If you don't have that check box selected, your game instance will pause when not focused (I'm guessing you don't want this if you're working with a client/host networking paradigm).

There are a few ways you can work around this. The ideal way to test a networked game would be to have a unique PC for each instance of the game.  If that's not an option, you can add some checks to ensure the mouse is over the window. As long as the two windows don't overlap you can do that by checking the position against the screen info:

```
bool IsMouseOverWindow()
{
    return !(Input.mousePosition.x < 0 || 
        Input.mousePosition.y < 0 || 
        Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width || 
        Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height);
}
```

You can then use this to decide, in your `Update()`, whether or not you want to update `rotator.rotation`.

Another option would be to implement [`MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html). You can then enable/disable things (like updating rotations based on `mousePosition`) in response to that event. The cleanest solution would be to have a clear way for your systems to ask "is my window focused".  You can make a class like this:

```
public class FocusListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool isFocused = true;
    void OnApplicationFocus (bool hasFocus) {
        isFocused = hasFocus;
    }
}
```

Make sure you have one of these somewhere in your game and then anything can check by looking at `FocusListener.isFocused`.

Comment: Thank you Gunther Fox for the response.  I really like that IsMouseOverWindow() method.  I will take a look at OnApplicationFocus and see how that works too.  Thank you again.

Comment: Gunther 1 follow up question.  When you mentioned the "Run in Background" idea, If I had this turned off would this work if I had my game running on a server that isn't my house and I connect via my client at my house?  Would that cause any issues like an auto disconnect?

Comment: @JoeyL If you're running a copy on a server, I would advise leaving "Run in Background" checked.  If you uncheck it and the application is un-focused on the server, it will discontinue to update and I'm certain that would cause disconnections and a failure to respond to clients.

Comment: Gunther what doesn't make sense to me is that Input.mousePosition code should not be ran.  It just like my movement code, I would say its almost identical. I have the same isLocalPlayer check and that works as both of my players do not move at the same time.  What doesn't make sense to me here is that for this script it seems both are being seen as local players bc now the 3 lines of code under the isLocalPlayer check are being ran.  I can edit to show my movement script if needed.

Comment: Gunther, added my movement code to get a better idea.

Comment: Oh god gunther I got it.  I didnt see the part where you said the differences between Input.mousePosition and Input.GetKeyDown.  I apologize for the extra comments.  I would assume Input.GetAxis() works the same as Input.GetKeyDown.  Thank you again.

Comment: @JoeyL I think the issue is the inconsistency of how `Input` works while an instance of the game is focused/unfocused (`mousePosition` will update for focused _and_ unfocused instances while `Input.GetAxis` and `Input.GetKeyDown` will update for focused _but not_ unfocused instances).  If you have a Server instance and Client instance running on the same machine, the mouse positions will update while in the background but the movement code will not.  I'd suggest completely ignoring all input code if your instance isn't focused.  I'll update my answer with a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you Gunther once again.  I am so happy and have a painted smile that I now have this working and on top of that I learned more new stuff.  I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @JoeyL Happy to help! :D